# Shell script does not work on crontab but works otherwise

Tags: scripts, cron, hadoop

I have a script which merges all the small files present at hourly directories at hdfs into one single large file. The script works OK when executed through CLI. I then set the script to run at 01:30 AM everyday to merge files of previous day. But it does not work. I exported PATH, HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR at the top of my script. Changed permission from user to root. But of no help. Here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0/bin:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/bin:/home/hadoopuser/zookeeper/bin:/home/hadoopuser/hive/bin:/home/hadoopuser/derby/bin:/home/hadoopuser/maven/bin:/home/hadoopuser/pig/bin:/home/hadoopuser/spark/bin:/home/hadoopuser/flume/bin:/home/hadoopuser/.local/bin:/home/hadoopuser/bin:/home/hadoopuser/user1/tmp

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoopuser/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/lib/native"

echo $HADOOP_HOME
echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
echo $PATH
mnth=$(date +%m)
day=$(date -d "1 day ago" +"%d")
echo "Running for $day-$mnth-2017"
for k in $mnth
do
     for j in $day
     do
         for i in 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
         do

           hadoop fs -cat /topics/topic1/year=2017/month=$k/day=$j/hour=$i/* | hadoop fs -put - /merged/topic1/2017"_"$k"_"$j"_"$i
           hadoop fs -du -s /merged/topic1/2017"_"$k"_"$j"_"$i > /home/hadoopuser/user1/merge_test/size.txt
           x=`awk '{ print $1 }' /home/hadoopuser/user1/merge_test/size.txt`
           if [ $x -eq 0 ]
           then
           hadoop fs -rm /merged/topic1/2017"_"$k"_"$j"_"$i
           else
           echo "MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour $i of $j-$k-2017 merged into one"
           fi
         done
    done
done

rm -f /home/hadoopuser/user1/merge_test/size.txt
```

Here is what I mention at `crontab -e`

```
30 1 * * * /home/hadoopuser/user1/tmp/cron-merge-generalevents.sh > /home/hadoopuser/user1/tmp/cron-merge-generalevents.txt
```

All I see in `/home/hadoopuser/user1/tmp/cron-merge-generalevents.txt` is for all the hours of a day

```
/home/hadoopuser/hadoop
/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/etc/hadoop
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0/bin:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/bin:/home/hadoopuser/zookeeper/bin:/home/hadoopuser/hive/bin:/home/hadoopuser/derby/bin:/home/hadoopuser/maven/bin:/home/hadoopuser/pig/bin:/home/hadoopuser/spark/bin:/home/hadoopuser/flume/bin:/home/hadoopuser/.local/bin:/home/hadoopuser/bin:/home/hadoopuser/user1/tmp
Running for 19-07-2017
MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour 17 of 19-07-2017 merged into one
MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour 18 of 19-07-2017 merged into one
MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour 19 of 19-07-2017 merged into one
MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour 20 of 19-07-2017 merged into one
MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour 21 of 19-07-2017 merged into one
MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour 22 of 19-07-2017 merged into one
MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour 23 of 19-07-2017 merged into one
```

Comment: Have you try to export JAVA_HOME? Better just source your `.bash_profile`

Comment: What is the contents of `size.txt`?

Comment: @jam is your script executable? `ls -l cron-merge-generalevents.sh`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I took your advice and exported the .bash_profile to my script. It worked. Thanks !!

Comment: @glennjackman At the end of the execution, it had the size of the last file. I anyway exported the .bash_profile in my script and it worked. crontab was able to pickup and execute my script. I think there was the issue of not exporting JAVA_HOME

Comment: @AFSHIN It was. Else normal execution would also not have happened.

Comment: @jam, in such case feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case good advice is to export also `JAVA_HOME` as you use hadoop which depends on java.
But the best is to import/source all the variables from `bash_profile`

(on the begin of script)

```
. /path/to/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source /path/to/.bash_profile
```